# How to initialize a global variable inside one function and access in another function inside Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst

I know a global variable should be initialized by contractor. what if need to init a global variable inside one function and access it in another function.

this is my first function

```
    public $customerId;

    public function store(CheckoutRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $customer = Stripe::customers()->create([
                                'source' => $request->stripeToken,
                                'email' => $request->email,
                                'description' => $request->name
                            ]);

            **$this->customerId** = $customer->id;
            $this->chargeCustomer($request, $customer->id);
            return redirect()->route('shipper.payment')->with('success_message', 'Thank you! your payment was successfull.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return back()->withErrors('Error! ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

this is my second function

```
    public function paymentDetails()
    {
        return $this->customerId;
    }
```

I'm creating customer in Stripe and assign created customer id to $customerId global variable, I need $customerId insid paymentDetails function which gets calling by another route, but paymentDetails return null. could anyone help please, how to get customer id in other functions?

Answer (score 0):

If you, as you describe, are calling `paymentDetails()` later via another route, then the public variable will not be set anymore. The controller is resolved per request, so it does not store anything for the next request.

Your best bet is probably to store some the customer on your own end and use that to retrieve the customerId on the next request, or maybe use https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session

Comment: I tried session, my front is vue n route is defined in api.php, as api is stateless session is not accessible there, I'm looking for a solution to store $customerId in the backend for later request. any other way?